# How to render template by dotliquid from custom object?

Tags: c#, dotliquid

I need dynamic rendering email template from the specific object from my domain model. I know I can create objects and inherit it from `Drop` class. Also, I know I can add the specific type to safe type globally, but this doesn't solve the problem.
How to render a template from my specific types?

```
var message = _template.Render(Hash.FromAnonymousObject(new {Item = User}));
public class User { public string Name { get; set;}.....}
```

Safe type doesn't suitable for this task because in my specific object has nested objects and I need an access to them too.

```
Template.RegisterSafeType(typeof(User,string[] allowedMembers));
```

I can inherit my specific types from `Drop` class of dotliquid assembly but I think it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

`RegisterSafeType` *is* the solution if you want to avoid `Drop` and the alternatives.

Simply register all the relevant types (approximate code):

```
Template.RegisterSafeType(typeof(User), userAllowedMembers);
```

Then say `User` has a property of type `Address`. You can simply continue the registration with

```
Template.RegisterSafeType(typeof(Address), addressAllowedMembers);
```

Answer (score -1):

```vb
Dim TemplateContent = CacheHelper.GetFileContentsNonCached("/Path/To/Template/File.htm")

Dim TemplateParsed = DotLiquid.Template.Parse(TemplateContent)
Return TemplateParsed.Render(Hash.FromAnonymousObject(New With {
  .Item = User,
  ......
}))
```

Above code is in VB.Net but easy to convert to C#. 
This doesn't require to register any type safe etc.

Comment: Your case doesn't work because User is a complex custom object with nested objects and lots properties. And dotliquid doesn't know how to cast this object. You need to inherit your type from ILiquidizable and implement ToLiquid method or you need to inherit your type from DROP class. Any other way doesn't work.

Comment: @PavelKononenko: I am using this technique for atleast 2 level deep properties and it is working fine for me. I use DROP class when I have to reuse the object for some other purpose as well. Otherwise, I just use dynamic.

Comment: How to dotliquid will know about a structure of your custom object? I implement code like you wrote at first in the beginning before I wrote here. It doesn't work. When you inherit drop a class you give dotliquid scheme of class.Thank you, but it's doesn't work for me.